# Find the Difference Between Two Arrays (Javascript Algorithm) + Funky Use of the Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

**Question**

Compare two arrays and return a new array with any items only found in one of the two given arrays, but not both. In other words, return the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

Note
You can return the array with its elements in any order.

**Professional Developers Answer**

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return [...diff(arr1, arr2), ...diff(arr2, arr1)];

  function diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(item => b.indexOf(item) === -1);
  }
}
```

**My Question**

I don't understand how this code operates. In particular I have never seen the spread operator used like this. Please could you explain how this works?

Comment: it is just concatenating two arrays together

Comment: Professional developer that uses spread syntax but not `includes` or `Set`? .oO

Answer (score 6):

It is just a fancy way to concat two arrays together. This is how it looks if you did not use the spread operator

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  function diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(item => b.indexOf(item) === -1);
  }

  var diff1 = diff(arr1, arr2)   // [0, 1]
  var diff2 = diff(arr2, arr1)   // [5, 6]
  return [].concat(diff1, diff2) // [0, 1, 5, 6]

}

var res = diffArray([0,1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5,6])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Or `diff1.concat(diff2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) used on an array takes the elements *out* of the array and puts them directly into the data structure that contains them. So if `A = [1,2,3]` and `B = [4,5,6]` then `[...A, ...B] === [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Without the spread operator, they would be `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`.